# I am getting the following error when I run mvn on OS X Mavericks: Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, macos, maven

I am running OS X Mavericks on a MacBook Pro.

I have maven 3.0.5 installed.

When I run mvn, I am getting the following error message.

```
Error while executing process. Cannot run program "/bin/sh": error-2, No such file or directory
```

And before you ask:

```
PATH="/usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin"

M2_HOME="/usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.5"

M2="/usr/local/apache-maven-3.0.5/bin"

MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

I am also seeing the following near the beginning of the mvn output:
    [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings

```
[WARNING] Failed to use environment variables for interpolation: Cannot run program "env": error=0, spawn failed @
```

Comment: Can you run `which sh` in your terminal and post the result?  `/bin/sh` be the proper directory of that executable unless you did something wonky.

Comment: /bin/sh does exist and it is executable by everyone

Comment: Which sh results are /bin/sh

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem: exec() failed with ANY executable.  Finally remembered that I was using a private jre. That jre was a copy of the original one, just with bin/java set as executable.

I made lib/jspawnhelper executable and it worked!

Comment: THIS SAVED ME SO MUCH!!! THANK YOU!  I'm on mac and I went through this terrible rabbithole learning about the mac gatekeeper, but it was just an executable problem all along.

Comment: exactly this - ran into this when just extracting OpenJDK 11 into a folder. chmod +x solved the issue!

Comment: I had been trying to figure this out for _days_. Apparently `jlink` stripped the execute bit from that file when it produced the Java bundle.

Comment: The exception message is misleading and its hard to find that after research. Therefore this answer is invaluable! And it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I searched hours for the reason exec was not working!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse , this is due to the java version. point java to your OS java instead of eclipse java. this will be solved

Answer (score -1):

It seems your system is missing the "sh" shell to start interpreting the script.

I just looked up installed shells on Mac OSX and got this result:

```
/bin/zsh
/bin/ksh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/bash
/bin/sh
```

So when "/bin/sh" is missing, try "/bin/bash" for example.

Better:

1. Check if "/bin/sh" exist
2. If exist check if the user which runs the command can execute the shell

Because it can be possible that the shell binary exist but isn't executable for you. Then you have to make it executable for the user trying mvn.

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: /bin/sh does exist and it is executable by everyone.

Comment: Then I don't have a clue, sorry