# Java on OS X: "open" command won't run if .app package contains a JVM bundle

Tags: java, macos, jar, .app

I'm trying to create a self-contained Mac app from a Java application. I've set up the .app directory, configured the `Info.plist` file, baked in dependencies as well as a Java runtime. I am successfully able to open the .app and launch the program and everything works except for one peculiar piece of code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("open", "/Applications/TextEdit.app");
pb.start();
```

When I launch the .app, this code does **not** seem to run or at least do anything. If I open the package contents and launch the .jar, it runs fine. I managed to narrow it down to happen only when the .app contains a Java runtime bundle. Since running a .jar uses the system's Java and running the .app uses the bundled Java, this has got to be the reason I'm struggling.

The version of my Mac's installed Java JDK should be 1.8.0_77.
The bundled version should be 1.8.0_74. I grabbed it from the [Moneydance](http://moneydance.com/) application as I used it for reference when making my .app.

Any help is very appreciated as this should be the final step to release it. I created this question to be more specific than my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36610422/os-x-java-app-bundle-cannot-open-other-apps).

Comment: It would be interesting to see a print of the PATH environment variable under the two JVMs.

Comment: @RealSkeptic It seems that both output the same PATH of `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: OK, then the next thing to do is tell us what the exact exit code from the process is, and if it's not zero, give us the content of the error stream.

Comment: I'm currently not running this from my workstation (but a Mac vm) so I'm kinda handicapped in terms of tools. What would be the easiest way to get this info? If I run the unix executable from the package, I'll get a Terminal log window, which doesn't prompt any errors. It only briefly displays `jspawnhelper` in the title bar when I click the button in the dummy app (though I guess that's unrelated).

I'll be back at my computer in some hours if need be, just trying to figure this out with that I've got in the mean time.

Comment: What I meant is that you have to change that Java application so that it prints out that information to a log - it should have something that gets the process result and reads the process error stream, otherwise that information is lost. Please note that for us to be able to help you your question should include the code in question, preferably in the form of a [mcve]. Nobody is going to run a downloaded zip by an unknown person, and it breaks the StackOverflow rules (see [help]).

Comment: Try calling the binary launcher directly.  For example: `/Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit`

Comment: @whiskeyspider Same result except it now also opens a Terminal window if ran from the jar. The .app still has no response.

Comment: I managed to figure out what was causing it. Not sure why but the bundled runtime itself didn't allow for it (the one I had copied from Moneydance). Perhaps they had stripped it of features they didn't use. I guess that's what I get for not doing it myself to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'll answer this myself as the issue was somewhat on my side.

The bundled JVM I was using (that I had copied from the Moneydance application) was the culprit. I suspect that the creators of Moneydance might have stripped their runtime bundle of features their app doesn't use in order to reduce the file size. Whatever the reason, my issue was fixed by creating my own bundle.

I did so by copying `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk` to `MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/`. After that I edited the `Info.plist` key called `JVMRuntime` to use the entry `jdk1.8.0_77.jdk`. My app now uses this JDK instead of the bundle I previously had, and `open` now works as it should.

Apologies for not doing my homework, but thank you to the people helping. I found the issue while writing reproduction steps, so I might not have found it without you. I guess all I can say to those who might experience something similar is to check your JVM bundle.

Comment: my jre bundle was missing an executable permission on jspawnhelper, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31015371/5858974